# Modelling a Non-Returning Call in UML

Tags: uml

I want to create a UML sequence diagram (see below) where I have an alt frame with two conditions (status equals foo or bar). In the foo case I send a synchronous message from A to B, get the return message and then proceed with the rest of the sequence diagram (call spam()). In the bar case I send another synchronous message from A to C to but there will be no return. I'm trying to model a function call in SW which doesn't return (it blocks forever on a semaphore) so in that case I will never proceed to spam(). Can this be expressed in a sequence diagram? I can exclude the return value but that would only tell me that there is no return **value**, not that there is no return at all. Can this only be expressed by splitting the diagram in two and handle the conditions separately or is there a better diagram to express this?

[image]

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you would include an image of the diagram you are working on.

Comment: @Geert Bellekens I've added an image as you suggested

Comment: Now I understand your question :). I don't know of a better way then to split in two diagrams, but maybe someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a duration constraint between the call and the return.

Under normal circumstances, such a constraint would be represented by an integer followed by a time unit, such as "10 seconds" or by a range such as "[1;10) seconds".

Your question is interesting in that you want to model infinity.
I would go about doing it like this:

[image]

However I must admit that I am unsure if my formulation violates [OMG's UML 2.5 standard](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF). I did not find anything in the standard which explicitly disallows using 'infinity' as a time unit; the standard does mention that the time should be relative.